# How to get "server console"

Tags: c++, console

I would like to write a server application which has a read in of the users commands but still outputting new events during the read in. It should look like e.g. the Minecraft server console.
I tried some things but nothing worked and I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I noticed that but I dont know how to set the position of the read in. Wasn't able to find something being able in std.

Answer (score 1):

Check out

> [http://www.amazon.com/Pocket-Socket-Programming-Kaufmann-Practical/dp/1558606866](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558606866)

This is a great guide to learning sockets.

I would look start with the very simple TCP Listener example in the book.

You'll want your server to listen to a socket, read (parse) user commands, and respond accordingly.

If you're not tied to C++, you can do this pretty darn quickly with a Perl/Python/Ruby or even C#.

Comment: I already know how that works. I mean the raw console which you can access e.g. via ssh on unix. How to manage to write all the time to it while reading in some command?

Answer (score 0):

Read about [libedit](http://www.thrysoee.dk/editline/) or [GNU Readline](http://www.gnu.org/s/readline/).